# выгрузка данныз через sql plus без иерголифов и кракозябр

Tags: oracle, кодировка, sqlplus

всем привет! У меня есть файл test.sql:

```
SET TRIMSPOOL ON;
SET ECHO OFF;
SET TRIMOUT ON;
SET LINESIZE 100;
SET PAGESIZE 0;
SET FEEDBACK OFF;
SET TIMING OFF;
SET VERIFY OFF;
SET TERMOUT OFF;
spool c:/test.csv;
whenever oserror exit 1
whenever sqlerror exit 2
select dg.id ||'|'|| dg.name ||'|'|| dg.provider_id from db.device_group dg;
SPOOL OFF;
EXIT;
```

его я прогоняю через sql plus... на выходе получаю

```
0|ІбХ УагЯЯл  гбваЮЩбвТ|0
1|ВХЫХдЮЭ|1
2|БЮХФШЭШвХЫмЭлХ ЫШЭШШ|1
3|АРФШЮвЮзЪР|1
4|АРФШЮвХЫХдЮЭ|1
```

ребят подскажите где и какие настраивать кодировки мне. Заранее спасибо!

Comment: кодировку ставить ту, которая у вас в консоли (зависит от вашей ОС). Для начала попробовать задать переменную окружения LANG

Comment: у меня win7... переменная окружения  NLS_LANG = AMERICAN_AMERICA.CL8ISO8859P5... можешь поподробней

Comment: http://www.sql.ru/faq/faq_topic.aspx?fid=217

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Запрос строки из БД выводит нечитабельные символы вместо кириллических](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/956206/%d0%97%d0%b0%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%be%d1%81-%d1%81%d1%82%d1%80%d0%be%d0%ba%d0%b8-%d0%b8%d0%b7-%d0%91%d0%94-%d0%b2%d1%8b%d0%b2%d0%be%d0%b4%d0%b8%d1%82-%d0%bd%d0%b5%d1%87%d0%b8%d1%82%d0%b0%d0%b1%d0%b5%d0%bb%d1%8c%d0%bd%d1%8b%d0%b5-%d1%81%d0%b8%d0%bc%d0%b2%d0%be%d0%bb%d1%8b-%d0%b2%d0%bc%d0%b5%d1%81%d1%82%d0%be-%d0%ba%d0%b8%d1%80%d0%b8%d0%bb%d0%bb%d0%b8%d1%87%d0%b5%d1%81%d0%ba%d0%b8%d1%85)